# using array_intersect_key on a single array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Binding] => Video Game
            [Brand] => Sony
            [Color] => Crystal black
            [EAN] => 0151903136010
            [Edition] => WiFi
         )
    [1] => Array(
            [Binding] => Console
            [Brand] => Nintendo
            [Color] => blk n wht
            [EAN] => 0045496880866
            [Edition] => Deluxe Set
         )
```

What I want to do is to be able to extract only the common keys, the value doesn't matter. The items in this array can range from 2 to 6.

It seems like `array_intersect_key` is the function that I'm looking for but it takes 2 or more arrays as an argument so I'll have to do something like:

```
$item_count = count($items);
if($item_count == 2){
  $intersection = array_intersect_key($items[0], $items[1]);
}else if($item_count == 3){
  $intersection = array_intersect_key($items[0], $items[1], $items[2]);
}
```

It feels like pretty tedious to do it this way. Any ideas what would be the easier and more elegant way to do this without using ifs? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [call_user_func_array()](https://www.php.net/call_user_func_array):

```
//$array is your original array
$result = call_user_func_array('array_intersect_key', $array);
```